# CircularDependencyError by inherting FK from Abstract Class

Tags: django, django-models, django-users

I have the following abstract class:

```
class UserStamp(models.Model):
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True,
                                   related_name='%(app_label)s_%(class)s_created_by', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    updated_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True, null=True,
                                   related_name='%(app_label)s_%(class)s_updated_by', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

The Account Model inherits from it:

```
class Account(UserStamp):
 pass
```

And I have a User Model with a FK to

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser,PermissionsMixin, UserStamp):
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account, blank=True, null=True, related_name='owner',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I have the following error when I migrate:

```
django.db.migrations.exceptions.CircularDependencyError:
```

The circular error I think appears because:

Account is calling User by inheriting created_by, updated_by from UserStamp, so points to User, and User points with Account FK back to Account.

If I use:

```
  account = models.ForeignKey('accounts.Account', blank=True, null=True, related_name='owner',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

the issues is not solved.

My problem has (2 issues), but I decided to split the initial question in 2 questions to be more clear(I think they can be solved separately):

[Second part here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48135650/update-the-instance-after-save-using-signals-by-conditionally-refference-back-t) (how to set created_by, updated_by)

Comment: You can just write referenced modem as string: 'app.model'.

Comment: See [production.manufacturer sample](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey)

Comment: @danihip I check the example, but in my case I have settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL (a custom user) not a direct model to use as string, which gives me an error if I try to use it as a string "Field defines a relation with model 'settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL', which is either not installed, or is abstract."

Comment: @danihp can elaborate, give an example based on my case (using 'accounts.Account' I still get the circular error)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize error was in migration but in models it self. What about None as default value and use post save signal to set value?

Comment: @danihip It is both (model and migration). I update the question, separated in 2 to be more clear; please take a look on both; I think your solution can help on the second part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a default user by modifying the `save()` method of your model:

```
class UserStamp(models.Model):
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True,
    ...
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.created_by:
           super_users = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL.objects.filter(
                is_superuser=True).order_by('date_joined')
           first_user = super_users[0]
           self.created_by = first_user
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

But I don't think that's what's causing your migration error. You may want to try a [OneToOneField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.OneToOneField)

Comment: I update my question to be more clear; please check the second part