# Update the instance after save, using signals by conditionally refference back to the instance in some cases

Tags: django, django-models, django-signals

I have the following abstract class:

```
class UserStamp(models.Model):
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True,
                                   related_name='%(app_label)s_%(class)s_created_by', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    updated_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True, null=True,
                                   related_name='%(app_label)s_%(class)s_updated_by', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

I have a custom User that inherits from User.

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser,PermissionsMixin, UserStamp):
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account, blank=True, null=True, related_name='owner',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

The User can create/update himself or by other user.

When the user create/update himself I don't have anything for created_by, update_by.

The user can be created using Django Admin or outside Django Admin;

In Django Admin the user can be created by staff, outside Django is self created;

Also there is superuser that is created in terminal;

Regarding the update the user in both Django Admin and outside can be self updated  or by another user.

I thought on using post_save or a custom signal. The issue is that request.user is not available in the model, but in View, and controlling the View in Admin and also in terminal(superuser) is a bottleneck.

Maybe trying to do a query after save passing the instance, but I don't exactly know how to combine all of them signal/query, check superuser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your own [**`custom signals`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/signals/).

#### *signals.py*

```
from django.dispatch import Signal 
# you can pass any number of arguments as per your requirement.
manage_user = Signal(providing_args=["user", "is_updated"])


def user_handler(sender, **kwargs):
    # `user` who created/updated object i.e `request.user`
    user = kwargs['user']
    # `is_updated` will be `False` if user object created.
    is_updated = kwargs['is_updated']
    # `sender` is the user object which is created/updated.
    ...
    # do your stuff

manage_user.connect(user_handler)
```

#### *models.py*

Override `save()` method of your custom user class.

```
from .signals import manage_user

class User(...):
    ...
    # call this save method like obj.save(created_by=request.user)
    def save(self, created_by, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        # is_updated will be True if user object is updated 
        manage_user.send(sender=self, user=created_by, is_updated=True if self.id else False)
```

> send `manage_user` signal when user model changed, just like `post_save` signal,
>   but now you have control over parameters.

### UPDATE

If you are using django admin to create user you can overide [save_model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model), you have request object there.

```
from django.contrib import admin

@admin.register(User)
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
     def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
         super(UserAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)
         manage_user.send(sender=self, user=request.user, is_updated=True if self.id else False)
```

Comment: you use request.user in the model save, and it doesn't exist, so I receive an error NameError: name 'request' is not defined and why use self(the instance) instead of the class as sender ?

Comment: you can add a extra parameter to your `save` method and send request.user where you are calling something like `obj.save(user=request.user)` or make use of `kwargs`

Comment: If I control the View yes, but using in admin or when I create the superuser I don't know how I can get request.user and by using self.id after calling super().save doesn't mean I always have the  self.id ?

Comment: Are you using ModelAdmin?

Comment: both, the user can be created using Django Admin or outside Django Admin; In Django Admin the user can be created by staff, outside Django is self created; also there is superuser that is created in terminal; regarding the update the user in both django Admin and outside can update itself or by another user

Comment: In case of terminal it is impossible to determine who is creating user, other wise for view you can do via call `save` with additional argument and via admin you can use ModelAdmin `save_model` method, check my update